# Programatically syncing multiple paths with Perforce doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, synchronization, perforce

It works when I sync with ONE String[], for example;

```
String[] paths = new String[]{//path1,//path2,//path3,etc.};
```

it will sync all the files into **ONE** target folder, say **"myFolder"**

```
IServer server = ServerFactory.getServer("myServer", null);
server.connect();
server.setUserName("myUsername");
server.login("myPass");
IClient tempClient = new Client();
tempClient.setName("tempClient" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", ""));
tempClient.setRoot("myFolder");
tempClient.setServer(server);
server.setCurrentClient(tempClient);
ClientViewMapping tempMappingEntry = new ClientViewMapping();
tempMappingEntry.setLeft("//Connect/...");
tempMappingEntry.setRight("//" + tempClient.getName() + "/...");
tempMappingEntry.setType(EntryType.INCLUDE);
ClientView tempClientView = new ClientView();
tempClientView.addEntry(tempMappingEntry);
tempClient.setClientView(tempClientView);
server.createClient(tempClient);
try
{
    List<IFileSpec> fileSpecsSet = FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList(pathsUnderDepot);//**HERE**
tempClient.sync(FileSpecBuilder.getValidFileSpecs(fileSpecsSet), true, false, false, false);
}
finally
{
    server.deleteClient(tempClient.getName(), false);
}
```

However, when I want to sync more than one folders, it does not sync to my target folders.
Here is what I got so far. The code is similar to the above with some changes:

```
each folder F has multiples paths to sync from

foreach forlder F in folderList
{
    IServer server = ServerFactory.getServer("myServer", null);
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    tempClient.setRoot(F);//**HERE**
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    try
    {
        List<IFileSpec> fileSpecsSet = FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList(F.paths);//**HERE**
    .....
    }
    finally
    {
        .....
    }
```

My question is how can I implement the code work as I expected. I think that the error come from two places (where I label **HERE** in the code).
Any helps or suggestions are appreciated.
Quan.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and solution.
The problem is that my paths include the date range which is **NOT** supported in **Perforce Sync**.

```
//path1/...@2014/05/16,2014/05/18
```

The error is in the **",2014/05/18"** 
.So, just get rid of the error part of the string, all the algorithms work smoothly.
Thanks those who took a look on my question.
Quan.